# authentification doesn't work in Laravel 8 with the @auth

Tags: php, html, laravel, laravel-8

So I have a Laravel application, I login and get redirected to my home page where the header is suppose to be changed but it isn't.

```
        <ul>
            <a  href="{{URL:: route( 'login' )}}" id="logo">
                <img src="{{asset('assets/img/rentalstallLogo.jpg')}}" alt="Logo">
            </a> 
            <li><a >Qui somme-nous</a> </li>
            <li><a >Événements & concours </a></li>
            @auth
            <li>
                <form action="{{ route('signout')}}" method="GET">
                @csrf 
                    <button type="submit" id='logoutButton'> logout </button>
                </form>
            </li>
            <li><a id="connexion-link" href={{route( 'login' )}}>account</a> </li>
            @endauth
            @guest
            <li><a href={{route( 'register-user' )}} >Inscriptions</a> </li>
            <li><a id="connexion-link" href={{route( 'login' )}}>Connexion</a> </li>
            @endguest
            <li><a id="language-link" href="#">fr</a> </li>
        </ul>
```

i also tried  `if (Auth::check())` and  `if (Auth->check())`

here is my log in function :

```
            'email' => 'required',
            'password' => 'required'
        ]);

        $credentials = $request->except(['_token']);

        $user = User::where('email',$request->email)->first();

        if (auth()->attempt($credentials)) {

            return redirect()->intended('/');
            

        }else{
            session()->flash('message', 'Invalid credentials');
            return redirect()->back();
        }
```

Comment: you can use `@if( auth()->check() )` and see it will work or not!

Comment: $auth = Auth::user()->id;..... dd($auth) what you have in debugging

Comment: @Tayyabmehar when I do that it gives me null.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use

@if(Auth::check())

@else

@endif

See it will work

Answer (score 0):

Sounds to me like the authentication process is not been completed correctly. You mentioned that dd($auth()->$user()) return null so that means the user is not being created correctly. In your login controller, you are only redirecting the user and not generating the session.

```
$request->session()->regenerate();
```

That line of code should be before the redirect. That should fix the $user returning null issue.